# Is it possible to alter the values in a dictionary, keeping the key value constant?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I need some clarification regarding altering the values in a dictionary,keeping the key constant.According to the problem definition I have a list as the value.The program runs a loop and has to group the values to it's parent(which is the key). So, is it possible to add elements to the list whenever the condition is satisfied?

for example: To group the numbers divisible by 4 and store it in a dictionary.

```
d={}
l=[]
for i in range(100):
    if(i%4==0):
        d.update({'Four':l.append(i)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
d = {'Four': []}
for i in range(100):
    if not i % 4:
        d['Four'].append(i)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
d = {'Four': [i for i in range(100) if not i % 4]}
```

Either way, you get:

```
d == {'Four': [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 
               44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 68, 72, 76, 80, 
               84, 88, 92, 96]}
```

---

If you will have more than just `'Four'`, you can either use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(100):
    if not i % 4:
        d['Four'].append(i)
```

or do the same thing "manually" yourself:

```
d = {}
for i in range(100):
    if not i % 4:
        if 'Four' not in d:
            d['Four'] = []
        d['Four'].append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks dude. But it throws an error if the key happens to be a number.

Comment: What error? Please provide full traceback. Integers and floats are both valid dictionary keys.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    d[1].append(3)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Btw,I was just checking if it works in a shell. d's initial value goes like this:
d={1:2,2:3,3:4}

Comment: The problem you have is that the *value* is an integer, not that the *key* is. The value should be a list of integers, not an integer. You have not implemented the provided code correctly, somewhere you must have e.g. `d[4] = i` rather than `d[4] = [i]` or similar.

Comment: ahhh.Yeah! Thanks a ton. Works like a charm. I forgot to initialize it as a list!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can edit a item in dictionary.

Look at your example:

```
d={}
for i in range(100):
    if(i % 4 == 0):
        # Update our list with the new one.
        if d.has_key('Four'):
            d['Four'].append(i)
        else:
            d['Four'] = [i]
```

Comment: But,does this code works for a key having a numerical value instead of string. Say, 4 instead of four??

Comment: Thanks a lot. But,will this suggestion work for a numerical key as well. Say,4 instead of 'Four'?

Comment: Yes, any hashable object can be a dictionary key and everything else will work exactly the same

Comment: But I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    d[1].append(3)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Thanks a ton. It would be better to initialize d['Four']=[] in order to make it compatiblle with different data types as I had learnt!